# Basic issue with SUMX

Tags: powerbi, dax

So I tried to make some dashboarding on my own. I made a little data base of sales (random data) in Excel.

In that database, there were 2 lines that held the same data :

[image]

so column A : clientnr, B : productnr; C: amount sold; D: date. (column E to H I made with a quick vlookup to check why the pbi file showed a different total)

So client 296 bought product 194 (=Mercury sable 2002 muave) 6 times in total. But this was registered 2 times in the data base (lets say het wanted 2 invoices ?)

Each line accounts for 121.25 dolla -> total sale towards client 296 that day would be (121.25 * 2) = 242.50 dolla

I checked with a pivottable:

[image]

Now in PBI (I found that the total sales for that day was higher than in my pivot, exactly for that amount)=

I make a table to check this, and it gives double the amount: so 484.99 dolla

[image]

for that measure "Total Revenue without disc(ount)" I used this formula:

[image]

So the sumx should give a "somproduct" between total units sold (from sales) & related sales price (linked via productkey).

Sales price for product 194 = 40.42 / product

(below is producttable[Salesprice] (print from excel):

[image]

so 6 sales would be = 242.50 dolla instead of the 484.99 dolla PBI shows.

I think the SUMX formule goes wrong because of the double "identical" lines in the sales table?

if so? Why and how to solve this (because this could be a reallife problem, exe customer wants 2 invoices or orders via 2 po's etc etc)..

Thanks for the help!

Kind regards,

Comment: Please put all code in text form and include the code for your measure `[Total Units Sold]` (I think that measure is your problem).

Comment: Hi Alexis, thanks for the help, as it was my first post, what do you mean with "al of the code in text form"?

Comment: the measure for Total Units sold was made with DAX

Comment: Total Units Sold = sum(sales[Units Sold])

Comment: What Alexis means is that it is better to sample code as text and not as image, easier to copy paste. As for your problem, I believe there is a mistake in your linking between the tables. Please give an overview of table relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't explain the issue in full detail, for that see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60668597/9614903

You are right having two identical rows is causing the problem.
SUMX generates a "Row Context" which is turned in an equivalent "Filter Context" by CALCULATE or by a call to a measure, it is a **global** filter.

Since you don't have an unique key in the table, the "Filter Context" matches more than one row and computes the calculation.
This gets repeated N times (because of the SUMX iterator), in the sample data two times.

The measure that is returning the wrong value (when computed in row context) is [Total Unit Sold], which returns 6 in every iteration instead of 3. 
You can see it by using a measure like: 
*check = SUMX([Total Unit Sold])*

To avoid this you have two options:

1. **reference columns inside SUMX** (instead of measure) - it should return the correct result since it does not create context transition: Revenue = SUMX(Sales, 'Sales'[QuantityColumn]*RELATED('Product'[Sale Price]))
2. **add an unique row id** - if you don't have it in the source data you can generate it in power query (Add Columns -> Index Column), this will prevent multiple rows to be matched when the context transition occurs.

Comment: Hi Giovanni! thanks a lot! I thought it was something like that! I will make it a habit to add a unique row id in those 'transaction' tables...

Comment: Glad it helped. if this actually solved the issue pls accept it as the answer